# Background color for a button is displayed faded in IE-9

Tags: html, css

Background color for a button is displayed faded in IE-9 and it works perfectly fine in other browser.

```html
<div id="pt1:_d_reg:region1:1:pt1:r1:0:r4:0:pt1:subf1:cb1" class="x2cg xhq p_AFTextOnly" style="background-color:#00822e; border-color:#00972b; border-style:solid; border-width:1.0px; background-image:none; background-repeat:repeat;" _afrgrp="0">
  <a onclick="this.focus();return false" class="xhp" href="#">
    <span class="xhu">Search</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Above is the snippet from the html. How to make this work?

Comment: <div id="pt1:_d_reg:region1:1:pt1:r1:0:r4:0:pt1:subf1:cb1" class="x2cg xhq p_AFTextOnly" style="background-color:#00822e; border-color:#00972b; border-style:solid; border-width:1.0px;background-image:none; background-repeat:repeat;" _afrgrp="0"><a onclick="this.focus();return false" class="xhp" href="#"><span class="xhu">Search</span></a></div>

Comment: Please add button in code .

Comment: Can you add all the related code and perhaps a screenshot of the button in IE as well please so we can see what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this by using the below style attribute:
filter: none !important

Thanks a lot for your comments guys.